# why Linux keeps killing Apache?

Tags: linux, apache, webserver

I have a long running apache webserver with lots of requests after sometime I find the apache server stopped with 
Killed line at the end

what can I do to solve this problem or prevent the system from killing the apache instance ??

Answer (score 1):

Linux usually kills processes when resources like memory are getting low. You might want to have a look at the memory consumption of your apache process over time.

You might find some more details here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136291/will-linux-start-killing-my-processes-without-asking-me-if-memory-gets-short

Also you can monitor your processes using the MMonit software, have a look here: https://serverfault.com/questions/402834/kill-processes-if-high-load-average

Answer (score 0):

The is a utility `top` which shows the process consumption (e.g. Mem, CPU, User etc), you can use it to keep an eye on apache process.